# Am I allowed to keep a copy of this pointer?

Tags: c++, winapi, com, windows-server-2012

I am writing a plugin for [Remote Desktop Connection Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd379632%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), in the [`ITsSbPlugin::Initialize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd379637%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method it states

> Plug-ins should call OnInitialized on the specified ITsSbPluginNotifySink sink object.

Which I do, however I noticed on the `ITsSbPluginNotifySink` it also has a [`OnTerminated()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd379635%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method. It does not say in [`ITsSbPlugin::Terminate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd379638%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that you need to call `OnTerminated()`, but should I?

And if I do need to call `OnTerminated()` should I be copying the passed in `ITsSbPluginNotifySink` to a local variable and using that to call `OnTerminated()`?

```
class CTsSbPluginProxy : public ITsSbPlugin
{
public:
    //(Snip)

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Initialize(
        __RPC__in_opt ITsSbProvider *pProvider,
        __RPC__in_opt ITsSbPluginNotifySink *pNotifySink,
        __RPC__in_opt ITsSbPluginPropertySet *pPropertySet);

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Terminate(HRESULT hr);


private:
    //(Snip)
    ITsSbPluginNotifySink *m_pNotifySink
};

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE CTsSbPluginProxy::Initialize(
    __RPC__in_opt ITsSbProvider *pProvider,
    __RPC__in_opt ITsSbPluginNotifySink *pNotifySink,
    __RPC__in_opt ITsSbPluginPropertySet *pPropertySet)
{
    //(Snip)

    m_pNotifySink = pNotifySink;
    m_pNotifySink->OnInitialized(S_OK);
    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE CTsSbPluginProxy::Terminate(HRESULT hr)
{
    //(Snip)

    //Is this legal?
    m_pNotifySink->OnTerminated();
    return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with these particular interfaces, but from the casual glance at the documentation, I'd say you are on the right track. There's one thing though: you must call `AddRef` on the pointer if you want to keep it beyond the `Initialize` call; and you must then call `Release` on it when you no longer need it (probably in `Terminate`, right after `OnTerminate` call). Otherwise, the object might be destroyed prematurely and you would be left with a dangling pointer.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I just discovered [this msdn arcive](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/rdsdev) which includes sample code, and they are doing similar to what I posted too. Post what you said as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN main documenation may be lacking, but I found [this msdn code archive](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/rdsdev/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3480). It contains a sample project where they do keep a copy of the `ITsSbPluginNotifySink` so I beleive I was correct in my first assumption that I should keep a copy of the pointer and release it at the end (also thank you to Igor Tandetnik [for reminding me about calling `AddRef`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20126386/am-i-allowed-to-keep-a-copy-of-this-pointer#comment29998217_20126386))

Comment: You can eliminate the need for AddRef/Release by using a smart pointer. Microsoft supplies some to choose from, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634996/which-com-smart-pointer-classes-to-use