# Writing a standard C++ wrapper for a COM dll

Tags: c++, com

I have a COM dll with a header that I want to write a C++ wrapper for to have a native C++ interface (no BSTR etc). It exports two functions to create and destroy a Foo object (plus various other functions to register/unregister the com dll, that I dont need). The Foo object is a member in the class `FooWrapper` and is used to call the function Bar on.
My approach works, but I am not sure about the memory allocation here.
The member `mFoo` is of type `IFoo*`, so should I rather use a smartpointer like this? :

```
std::auto_ptr<IFoo*>  msFoo = std::auto_ptr<IFoo*>(new IFoo*);
```

What exactly is `IFoo*` and why does it derive from `IDispatch`?
This is my class so far:

```
class FooWrapper{
public:

FooWrapper(){CreateFoo();}
~FooWrapper(){DestroyFoo();}
void CreateFoo(){//Uses DLL Funtcion to create Foo object}
void DestroyFoo(){//Uses DLL Funtcion to destroy Foo object}

void Bar(std::string sName)
{
BSTR sbName = SomeStaticClass::ConvertToBSTR(sName);
    HRESULT hRes = mFoo->Bar(sbName);
    if (hRes != S_OK)
     throw exception;
}

protected:
IFoo * mFoo;
};
```

FooHeader.h:

```
MIDL_INTERFACE("B32876428-AAAA-8742-A224-XXXXXXXXXXX")
IFoo : public IDispatch
{
 public:
   virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Bar(BSTR name) = 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use a standard smart pointer for COM objects, they have their own unique way of managing the pointer lifetime. Microsoft makes a couple of smart pointer types specifically for them.

Comment: You have to call a factory function like CoCreateInstance() in your constructor and mFoo->Release() in your destructor.  Why you want to use auto_ptr is very unclear, it accomplishes nothing at all since an interface doesn't have a destructor.

Comment: @HansPassant: `auto_ptr` is wrong, but one of the MS smart pointers is exactly right.  It means you never have to worry about calling AddRef or Release.

Comment: Thanks! I suppose you are referring to `CComPtr` ?

Comment: There's more than just `CComPtr`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634996/which-com-smart-pointer-classes-to-use